# How can we show WPF button contents on MouseOver with transperent background

Tags: wpf, xaml

i want the WPF button behaves in a way on mouse over only  i want to show content of button (its an image)
 and also on mouseover i want the background as transparent + no border .
Button content is an image and i am giving a padding of 50 px . so mouse is anywhere near to 50px on button i can see the button content. 
The xaml i used is

```
  <Button  Style="{StaticResource FadeOutButton}" Padding="50" Opacity="0" >                        
                    <Image Source="Images\myimage.JPG"></Image>
```

and

```
  <Style x:Key="FadeOutButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>            
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard >
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard >
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

What else i have to add to make the background transparent on mouseover in addition to current effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FadeOutButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOverAnimation" >
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOutAnimation">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" >
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOverAnimation}" />
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOutAnimation}" />
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Button  Style="{StaticResource FadeOutButton}" Padding="50" Opacity="0" >
    <Image Source="Screenshot_3.png"></Image>
</Button>
```

Comment: Yes it produce the expected output . But Padding is ignored completely. I put a padding of 50px on the Button , but i can see the image content is not using the spacing at all

Comment: try by setting <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />

Comment: But it ignore mouse over of margin area . Only on image (content of button ) mouse over i can see the button content. if i put mouse over the padding space inside button , nothing happends

Comment: added <Border Background="Transparent"/> please see edit